# Moving a button in microsoft forms using c# / changing its size?

Tags: c#, winforms

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.AutoSize = false;

    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        double sz = button1.Size.Width;

        sz = sz - 1;
    }
}
```

I got this and I'm pretty lost, nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Any control like a button have 4 properties 1) Left 2) Top 3) Height 4) Width  You do not need Size.

Comment: You need to actually set the width: `button1.Width = ...`

Comment: Nothing happens because you do nothing with the new size. In any case, even if you set the new width of the button at each loop you will see only the last width applied to the button. Changes to a winformsUI interface doesn't happen automatically inside a loop.

Comment: Are you trying to move the buttons location, or are you trying to resize your button? Your question is confusing, and your code doesn’t work because you’re not setting any size or location, you’re only placing the width value in a variable..

Comment: You need to put `button1.Size.Width = sz;` after `sz = sz - 1;`

Comment: @SkiSharp you can't. Size is structure. You can't change it in place, See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1612

Comment: My mistake.  You can if you remove `Size` and just use `Width` so `button1.Width = sz;` will work. At least it does in VS 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work mainly because you don't change the button size, but apart from this, the code suffers also from another problem. The visible changes to an UI elements in WinForms are executed (repaint) only when your code exits from the event handler. So, simply changing the size of the button is not enough to produce the effect of a shrinking button to a different size.

Without knowing exactly what is your intent beside resizing the button, this could be a possible solution. Pay attention to the comments inside this sample.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Very important: Disable the button to avoid another click while
    // you are still running inside the loop
    button1.Enabled = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        // Change the button's size
        button1.Width -= 1;

        // Wait for 10ms to allow the winforms engine to repaint the button
        Task.Delay(10).Wait();

    }
    // Now you can reenable the button.
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

The important thing is the button's enable/disable steps to avoid reentry on the click event. However, this is incomplete and dangerous if you have other controls still active that can raise their own events while the loop is still running. These kind of graphics effects are not WinForms engine best friends.

Comment: Just be aware that as written, `Task.Delay(10).Wait();` is actually BLOCKING the UI thread.  If you were to increase the 10 to something bigger, and try to drag the form by the titlebar as it runs, you'll get no response.  The fix would be to pop `async` between `private` and `void` and switch to using `await Task.Delay(10);`.  As Steve said, though, there can be other unintended consequences of the user interface when we start dealing with asynchronous code.  You have to very careful and thorough in your design process...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that illustrates my comment in Steve's post:

> Just be aware that as written, Task.Delay(10).Wait(); is actually
> BLOCKING the UI thread. If you were to increase the 10 to something
> bigger, and try to drag the form by the titlebar as it runs, you'll
> get no response. The fix would be to pop async between private and
> void and switch to using await Task.Delay(10);. As Steve said, though,
> there can be other unintended consequences of the user interface when
> we start dealing with asynchronous code. You have to very careful and
> thorough in your design process...

Instead of changing size of the button, let's make it blink.  The duration between changing colors would be increased, then, so you can see the colors changing.  The larger increase in time will make it obvious that the form is not responding with the below code.  Try dragging the form around by the titlebar as the button blinks:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled  = false;

    bool blink = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        blink = !blink;
        button1.BackColor = blink ? Color.Red : Control.DefaultBackColor;
        Task.Delay(250).Wait();
    }

    button1.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

By adding `async` and switching to `await Task.Delay()`, the form will remain responsive as the button blinks:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled  = false;

    bool blink = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        blink = !blink;
        button1.BackColor = blink ? Color.Red : Control.DefaultBackColor;
        await Task.Delay(250);
    }

    button1.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```